# How to get approval to give my book to a friend?

Tags: united-states, export

I live in the Netherlands and I received a book I ordered from a company in the US. The package I received today had an invoice included. The invoice had the following text printed on it:

> These items are controlled by the U.S. government and authorized for export only to the country of ultimate destination for use by the ultimate consignee or end-user(s) herein identified. They may not be resold, transferred, or otherwise disposed of, to **any other country** or to **any person other than the authorized ultimate consignee** or end-user(s), either in their original form or after being incorporated into other items, without first obtaining approval from the U.S. government or as otherwise authorized by U.S. law and regulations.

It is obvious that I need approval from US authorities to give my book to a friend in living in Belgium and probably also to give my book to a friend in the Netherlands. How do I get approval?

Comment: This is called a _[Destination Control Statement](https://www.trade.gov/destination-control-statement-dcs)_ (DCS for short) and is basically there to provide CYA-insurance to the seller.

Answer (score 4):

There is something wrong-sounding about that claim. Owning a thing (such as a book) means that you can dispose of it however you want. If it is a physical book, then unless this is a book of top secret classified information, the US government has no control over the item, nor does the copyright holder have any right to prevent you from giving away your copy. Electronic books, however, are another matter, since often you don't buy such books, you buy a license to use the book (like a software license). The license terms of an electronic book could be subject to various controls, and the license might be non-transferable. The underlying logic of this is that under the doctrine of first sale, you are allowed to do whatever you want with intellectual property that you buy, and therefore to restrict re-distribution of electronic IP, software especially is typically not itself sold, and just the permission to use it is.

If this is an electronic book, the copyright holder would be able (though not necessarily willing) to permit you to transfer your copy to someone else. Of course you can't give a copy to two people unless you have two licenses.

Comment: There are military technology and trade embargo rules, not intellectual property protections. The first sale rule bars intellectual property protection in these circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

You need to submit an application to the [U.S. Treasury Department Office of Foreign Asset Control (OFAC)](https://www.ucop.edu/ethics-compliance-audit-services/compliance/export-control/export-laws.html), or State Department’s Directorate of Defense Trade Controls (DDTC), or the Bureau of Industry and Security (BIS) within the Department of Commerce, as applicable. It takes three to six months to get approval, which is not guaranteed.

If you are giving it to a national of Belgium or the Netherlands who isn't on a terrorist watch list, and you were able to get it, it will probably be approved as a matter of course, however.

The issue is not copyright, but U.S. national security. If it is a book, it probably involves classified technologies such as cryptography, nuclear physics and engineering, chemical or biological weapons, advance computer designs, or anti-radar stealth or something like that.

> The Export Administration Regulations (EAR) are implemented by the
> Bureau of Industry and Security (BIS) within the Department of
> Commerce. The EAR regulates the export of “dual use” goods and
> services (goods and services having both military and civilian uses)
> that are identified on the Commerce Control List (CCL). These are
> items that are not inherently military in nature; they are primarily
> commercial items with potential military uses.
>
> The International Traffic in Arms Regulations (ITAR) are implemented
> by the State Department’s Directorate of Defense Trade Controls
> (DDTC). These regulations apply to articles, services, and related
> technical data that are inherently military in nature, as determined
> by the State Department. These “defense articles,” "defense services,”
> and related “technical data” are listed on the U.S. Munitions List
> (USML). Some articles and technologies that are not readily
> identifiable as inherently military in nature—for example, research
> satellites or small, research submersibles—are included on the USML.
>
> The Treasury Department’s Office of Foreign Assets Control (OFAC)
> implements the economic and trade sanctions and, based on U.S. foreign
> policy and national security goals, targets foreign countries,
> terrorists, international narcotics traffickers, and those engaged in
> activities related to the proliferation of weapons of mass
> destruction. The university typically encounters issues arising under
> the OFAC regulations when researchers engage in collaborations with
> foreign nationals overseas or seek to teach classes or perform
> research in foreign countries.

Comment: Please clearly indicate the source of the quote here. I am sure it is accurate and from a reliable, probably an official, source, but please be explicit about the source.

Comment: I'm sure that info is correct; but if Daan is not a US Citizen, not residing in the US, is there any legal justification to assume any US regulations apply?

Comment: @DavidSiegel The source is from the link in the answer, it is UC-Berkley's office for handling those matters.

Comment: @AskAboutMonica The hook would be that one would have agreed to be bound by those regulations as a condition to receiving the book.